# Call Function Postgresql

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I want to insert table lokasi from function... but when i call these function there are error... Please your answer

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_lokasi2
  (anip character varying, aeksemplar character varying)
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
  eks integer;
  tot integer;
  nilai boolean;
  eks1 integer;
  eks2 integer;
  tot2 integer;

BEGIN

   select sum(CAST(eksemplar AS INT)) 
     INTO eks 
     from lokasi 
    where nip = anip;

   tot := eks + aeksemplar;

   select CAST(eksemplar AS INT) 
     INTO eks1 
     from sensus 
    where nip = anip;

   select CAST(eksemplar2 AS INT) 
     INTO eks2 
     from sensus 
    where nip = anip;

   tot2 := eks1 + eks2;

   IF (tot <> tot2) THEN
     nilai := false;
   else 
     nilai := true;
   END IF;

   RETURN nilai;

END 

$BODY$

  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE

  COST 100;

  ALTER FUNCTION insert_lokasi2(character varying, character varying) OWNER TO postgres;

  select * from insert_lokasi2('10.1010.4703','1');
```

ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer + character varying

```
LINE 1: SELECT   $1  +  $2 
                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT   $1  +  $2 
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "insert_lokasi2" line 12 at assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

`eks` is an integer whilst `aeksemplar` is a string. You need a cast by your addition:

```
tot := eks + CAST(aeksemplar AS INT)
```

Better would be to either do all these castings at the top of the finction or, if possible, change the argument types so that the casting is unecessary.